# Can't log JSON data from nodejs + express when serving static files with express use but can see it when I call only get JSON data and not the statics

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to learn how to send data from nodejs + express server to front-end static files, where javascript (allScripts.js) will be used to process it. Currently I'm trying to at least log it to console to see if I'm correctly sending it to the front-end.

Initially I wanted to send data from sqlite database to front-end, however due to lack of knowledge I reduced it to sending a simple array of objects as JSON using nodejs and displaying it in browser console for now. Unfortunately, it's resulting in

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Here is the server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    const users = [
        {id:'123',
        name:'Shaun'},
        {id:'234',
        name:'Bob'},
        {id:'345',
        name:'John'},
        {id:'456',
        name:'Oliver'},
    ]
    res.json(users);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port ",PORT)
});
```

Removing app.use, however, is allowing me to see the users table like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n109d.png)

Here is the static javascript (allScripts.js) snippet to print the data:

```
fetch('../').then(response => response.json())
        .then(users => console.log(users));
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
/ ---- nodejs server file

\ ---- public
    ---- index.html
    ---- style.css
    ---- allScripts.js
```

I will edit the question to provide any further details if required.

Comment: Did you try passing the JavaScript object to `JSON.stringify()` before passing the `res.json()`? You should be able to just use `node:http`, `node:fs`, `node:url`, `node:path` without any third-party libraries.

Comment: From what I understood, I added JSON.stringify(users) before res.json(users). Still the same error. Could the problem possibly be in the way I'm processing the JSON data in the static javascript (allScripts.js)?

Comment: add this line `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: Tried adding that both before and after express.static('public'). Still no use.
I read a bit about app.use(express.json());, apparently it's useful for logging to node console? What I'm trying to do is log it to browser console, ie frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I fixed it by making a separate location for the app.get for the API call(Main intention was a custom API, but I'll demonstrate it with this one). Here's the fixed code:

```
app.get('/api', (req,res) => {
    const users = [
        {id:'123',
        name:'Shaun'},
        {id:'234',
        name:'Bob'},
        {id:'345',
        name:'John'},
        {id:'456',
        name:'Oliver'},
    ]
    res.json(users);
});
```

And for the fetch snippet:

```
fetch('../api').then(response => response.json())
        .then(users => console.log(users));
```